# Sorting one element of the tuple while other element stays with it unchanged

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
w = [10,20, 30, 40, 50]
v = [20, 30, 66, 40, 60]

ratio = []
for i in range(len(w)):
    item = v[i]/w[i]
    ratio.append(item)

# making a tupe of ratio and weight
w_ratio = tuple(zip(ratio,w))
```

I want to sort the ratio while the weight should remain associated with it. I want this:

```
((2.2,30),(2,10),(1.5,20),(1.2,50),(1,40))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your tuples to `sorted` with the argument `reverse=True` to specify descending order.

```
>>> w = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> v = [20, 30, 66, 40, 60]
>>> ratio = [i/j for i,j in zip(v,w)]
>>> sorted(zip(ratio, w), reverse=True)
[(2.2, 30), (2.0, 10), (1.5, 20), (1.2, 50), (1.0, 40)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` is what you need.

```
w = [10,20, 30, 40, 50]
v = [20, 30, 66, 40, 60]

ratio = []
for i in range(len(w)):
    item = v[i]/w[i]
    ratio.append(item)
w_ratio = tuple(zip(ratio, w))
w_ratio = sorted(w_ratio, reverse = True)
```

**Output**

[(2.2, 30), (2.0, 10), (1.5, 20), (1.2, 50), (1.0, 40)]

Comment: I found a better and efficient way. Want me to share it or its cool?

Comment: @m416_new sure, always open to better solutions. Please share